# hippo cms- number of document getting limited to 5

Tags: hippocms

I'm using hippo cms for one of my project and it has a document type for storing the contact us details.In my CMS repository there are 9 contact us document(all published), however on my application only 5 are getting displayed, other 4 are not displaying.
If I change the display order of the document then the the invisible document shows on the application but other document disappears.
There are no limit used in the jsp or in the CMS.
Can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

```
<sv:node xmlns:sv="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0" sv:name="home">
  <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
    <sv:value>hst:component</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:property sv:name="hst:referencecomponent" sv:type="String">
    <sv:value>hst:pages/standard</sv:value>
  </sv:property>
  <sv:node sv:name="main">
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
      <sv:value>hst:component</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:node sv:name="content">
      <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
        <sv:value>hst:component</sv:value>
      </sv:property>
      <sv:property sv:name="hst:referencecomponent" sv:type="String">
        <sv:value>hst:components/content</sv:value>
      </sv:property>
      <sv:property sv:name="hst:template" sv:type="String">
        <sv:value>home.main.content</sv:value>
      </sv:property>
    </sv:node>
    <sv:node sv:name="lists">
      <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
        <sv:value>hst:containercomponent</sv:value>
      </sv:property>
      <sv:property sv:name="hst:componentclassname" sv:type="String">
        <sv:value>org.hippoecm.hst.pagecomposer.builtin.components.StandardContainerComponent</sv:value>
      </sv:property>
      <sv:property sv:name="hst:xtype" sv:type="String">
        <sv:value>HST.UnorderedList</sv:value>
      </sv:property>

      <sv:node sv:name="contacts">
        <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
          <sv:value>hst:containeritemcomponent</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="hst:componentclassname" sv:type="String">
          <sv:value>org.rf.online.components.Contacts</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="hst:iconpath" sv:type="String">
          <sv:value>images/catalog-list.png</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="hst:label" sv:type="String">
          <sv:value>Contacts</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="hst:parameternames" sv:type="String" sv:multiple="true">
          <sv:value>title</sv:value>
          <sv:value>scope</sv:value>
          <sv:value>docType</sv:value>
          <sv:value>sortBy</sv:value>
          <sv:value>backgroundColor</sv:value>
          <sv:value>sortOrder</sv:value>
          <sv:value>secondSortBy</sv:value>
          <sv:value>secondSortOrder</sv:value>
          <sv:value>pageSize</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="hst:parametervalues" sv:type="String" sv:multiple="true">
          <sv:value>contact</sv:value>
          <sv:value>/</sv:value>
          <sv:value>rfonline:contactsdocument</sv:value>
          <sv:value>rfonline:contactRegionOrder</sv:value>
          <sv:value>light</sv:value>
          <sv:value>ascending</sv:value>
          <sv:value>rfonline:contactOrder</sv:value>
          <sv:value>ascending</sv:value>
          <sv:value>21</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="hst:template" sv:type="String">
          <sv:value>standard.main.contacts</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
        <sv:property sv:name="hst:xtype" sv:type="String">
          <sv:value>HST.Item</sv:value>
        </sv:property>
      </sv:node>
    </sv:node>
  </sv:node>
</sv:node>
```

Here is my home.xml that has the pageSize attribute set to 21. I increased it to 50, but still the total documents are not getting displayed.

The pageSize attribute is not used in Contacts.java, however the Contacts class extends BaseComponent class in which  pageSize is used.
Here is the code snippet from Contacts and BaseComponent classes.

```
    @ParametersInfo(type = ContactsInfo.class)
    public class Contacts extends BaseComponent{
        //code
    }

public abstract class BaseComponent extends BaseHstComponent {

public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseComponent.class);

protected void createAndExecuteSearch(final HstRequest request, final GeneralParamsInfo info, final HippoBean scope, final Map<String,Object> queryMap) throws HstComponentException {
        int pageSize = info.getPageSize();
        if (pageSize == 0) {
            log.warn("Empty pageSize or set to null. This is not a valid size. Use default size");
        }
        try {
            HstQuery hstQuery = getQueryManager(request).createQuery(scope, filterClass, true);
       hstQuery.setLimit(pageSize);
       hstQuery.setOffset(pageSize * (crPage - 1));
          if (sortBy != null && !"".equals(sortBy)) {
            if (sortOrder == null || "".equals(sortOrder)||"descending".equals(sortOrder)) {
                    hstQuery.addOrderByDescending(sortBy);
                } else {
                    hstQuery.addOrderByAscending(sortBy);
                }
            }
            String querys = null;           
    }           
    final Object attribute = request.getAttribute("isPageableCollection");
    final Boolean isPageableCollection = (Boolean) (attribute != null ? attribute : false);
            if (info instanceof PageableListInfo && ((PageableListInfo) info).isPagesVisible()) {
                 if (result.getTotalSize() > pageSize) {
                    List<Integer> pages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    int numberOfPages = result.getTotalSize() / pageSize;
                    if (result.getTotalSize() % pageSize != 0) {
                        numberOfPages++;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
                        pages.add(i + 1);
                    }
                    request.setAttribute("pages", pages);
                }
            }

        } catch (QueryException e) {
            throw new HstComponentException("Exception occured during creation or execution of HstQuery. ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my ContactInfo interface:-

```
public interface ContactsInfo extends GeneralParamsInfo {

     @Parameter(name = "scope", defaultValue="/", displayName = "Scope")
     @DocumentLink(docType = "rfonline:contactsdocument")
        String getScope();

     @Override
    @Parameter(name = "docType", displayName = "Document Type", defaultValue="rfonline:contactsdocument")
    String getDocType();

     @Parameter(name = "backgroundColor", defaultValue="light", displayName = "Background Color")
     String getBackgroundColor();

}
```

Comment: You should provide some relevant code

Comment: Can you also post some snippets of code from the Contacts.java class in which the pageSize attribute is used?

Comment: @Jeroen I have added some code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a "pageSize" component parameter set to 5.
Please check if your component is annotated with @ParametersInfo pointing to a parameters info interface with default page size value, or if your component reads/sets the page size value while searching.

Comment: The pageSize is set to 10.  @Parameter(name = "pageSize", displayName = "Page Size", defaultValue="10")
int getPageSize();

Comment: In that case could you update your original post with this information and perhaps the show some code of your custom component or mentions which component you are using exactly?

Comment: Is there anyway that the total number of documents can be limited??